# How to pass flags to nodejs application through npm run-script?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, package.json

I've a NodeJS file that I run via an "npm" command. I've been trying to list all arguments (including flags). If I run it by directly calling the node exe, it works fine but if I use the `npm` command, I cannot access the flags.

Code:

```
console.dir(process.argv);
```

When I run the file like this,

```
node file.js arg1 arg2 -f --flag2
```

I can get all of the arguments.

```
[ '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/.../file.js',
  'arg1',
  'arg2',
  '-f',
  '--flag2' ]
```

But if I add an npm runner to the package.json file and try to run with it, I can only get the arguments but not the flags.

```
npm run test arg1 arg2 -f --flag2
```

The result:

```
[ '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/.../file.js',
  'arg1',
  'arg2' ]
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "test" : "node test.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Basically, node won't pass flags to the running script. Is there a solution for this? My real project has a long path with a lot of arguments so I want to use a shortcut to test it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a double dash before arguments:

```
npm run test -- arg1 arg2 -f --flag2
```

Comment: If your args look like `--reset`, you can use `npm run test -- --reset`

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a difference this makes, but I was attempting to do "npm run ng serve -o", but in order to get the "o" (for opening a new browser window) recognized, I had to type it like "npm run ng serve -- -o" with a single dash in front of the "o" instead of a double-dash.

Comment: @KSwift87 the double dash isn't in front of the o instead of a single dash, the double-dash marks the end of the arguments to npm and the beginning of the arguments that npm is supposed to pass to the program it is going to run