# Run an optional script with yarn by parsing it as a flag

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

We have a script in a `create-react-app`. Its main job is to enable me to run my frontend in react app alone without the need to run the backend API.

So here's what we came up with:

```
const fake_user = {
  user_id: 1,
  full_name: 'John D.',
  role: 'tutor'
} // only used in dev environment

async getUser() {

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      return fake_user
    }
  ..... // other auth code for production.
}
```

What this gives us, however, is a one-way route to only run dev env with the fake user, but what we actually want is to be able to run the react app with the fake user, optionally and not by default.

Usually, when we want to run a react app we type, `yarn start` but now we want to be able to pass in a flag, how do we achieve that?
How can we get something like this to work? `yarn start --with-fake-user`

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760799/how-to-pass-flags-to-nodejs-application-through-npm-run-script) might help you

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I saw this already. Doesn’t work for my use-case. Except I’m missing something. If you know how to approach the task based on the answer you shared, pls post an answer.

Comment: In the script that the command `yarn start --with-fake-user` invokes have you utilized nodes [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to determine whether the flag `--with-fake-user` has been passed to it? Further info regarding extracting command line args can be found in this [blog](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2018/10/extracting-command-line-arguments-nodejs/).