# How to prevent npm run lint from fixing errors automatically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, eslint, prettier

I created a Vue3 app using the Vue CLI with a Prettier/Eslint setup. When modifying the main.ts file to

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

createApp(App)
.use(router).mount("#app");
```

and run `npm run serve` I get the following warning

> 6:15  warning  Delete `⏎`  prettier/prettier

as expected. Running `npm run lint` fixes it. But which flag is required to only check for the style?

I have a GitHub action workflow checking the code style and using `npm run lint` is wrong because the workflow fixes the code style and passes.

When searching for a flag I run `npx vue-cli-service help lint` which tells me to use `--no-fix`

[image]

but running `npm run lint --no-fix` it still fixes the file

[image]

So which command should I use inside my GitHub action to ensure the workflow fails on invalid code style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a double dash before your arguments, so use `npm run lint -- --no-fix` with `--` as extra prefix instead of `npm run lint --no-fix`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760799/how-to-pass-flags-to-nodejs-application-through-npm-run-script).